# Best way to encrypt large amounts of text data in Android application?

Tags: android, encryption, proguard

I have an Android application in development that has a large amount of text based data (essentially the app is a reference/learning guide).

I would like to make sure that if in the event the prograded version of the APK on the device is pulled from the device and "decompiled", the textual data is somehow encrypted.  Is there any way to encrypt text data so that the text is not useable  if extracted?

Comment: What makes you think that the key that was used to encrypt your texts is not extracted from the apk and used to decrypt those texts?

Comment: This key issue is exactly why I asked the question. I have already run into the key issue and I am assuming from your response that you at least know of no way to secure a key and still allow access to data. I am assuming it is probably just not doable but I still had to ask.

Comment: That's right. Obfuscators like proguard can only hide such information against lazy "hackers", but not perfectly protect such information. And if you want to encrypt something, then you still need the decryption key somewhere close.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the text with AES encryption. Use PKCS#7 née PKCS#5 padding and CBC mode with a random IV, prepend the IV to the encrypted data. You should also prepend a hash of the encrypypded data for authentication.

You can look at [RNCryptor-Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md) for an idea of the data layout. 
[RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor) for an implementation  including IV, encryption authentication, versioning.

Comment: thanks for all the links on encryption methods.  The biggest issue I have had with any encryption method I have came across is in regards to having to have the key "exposed" in the apk to access the encrypted data.  Any thoughts on how to somehow not expose the key but somehow still encrypt/un-encrypt the data in the code.  (I realize this is a tall order but I figured someone out there has had to face this issue before and come up with some clever ideas/workarounds).  Even If I could just encrypt the APK beyond what pro guard offers that would be great.

Comment: Keeping the encryption key secret is a problem there is no complete solution to on a phone. Obviously while using the key for encryption/decryption it must be in memory and can be obtained by a skilled atttacker. If the  key is compiled into the app it can be accessed by anyone who can obtain access to the app binary, the best that can be done is to obfuscate it somehow, possibly encoding and splitting it into pieces, search for such methods. If the key is created at runtime keep it in the Android Keystore, note the user will have access to that. What you may need is a DRM solution.

Comment: You may have hit on a solution in splitting the key and then somehow using the obfuscation process to make it virtually impossible for the user to put the key back together. I will dig into proguards obfuscation process to see how "complete" I can make this process.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I believe an interested party can step through your code with a debugger, so a bespoke obfuscator won't work. The Android Keystore api works outside of your application's process for this reason (as far as I know).

Comment: It is all about increasing the work factor since there is no 100% protection available. Determine the capabilities and interest of the attacker along with the value of what is being protected and try to protect against that. Given that obfuscation is not particularly secure it does increase the work factor.